# Why are my array values being replaced instead of added?

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing a PHP library that is meant to include JavaScript tags and code in the footer of my page after adding them in controllers.  I have methods that add src tags and tags that contain code.  The add_src method is supposed to add either arrays or single srcs to the ones that have already been set.  For some reason, only the last item in the arrays are being added to the sources.  The code outputs fine.

The library:

```
<?php

class JS {

    var $js_code = '';
    var $js_srcs = array();

    function add_code($js = ''){
        $this->js_code .= $js;
        return $this;
    }

    function add_src($src = '', $type = ''){
        if(is_array($src)){
            foreach($src as $type => $url){
                $this->js_srcs[] = script_tag($src, $type);
            }
        } else {
            $this->js_srcs[] = script_tag($src, $type);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    function reset_code(){
        $this->js_code = '';
        return $this;
    }

    function reset_srcs(){
        $this->js_srcs = array();
        return $this;
    }

    function generate(){
        $str = '';
        if(count($this->js_srcs) > 0){
            foreach($this->js_srcs as $src){
                $str .= $src;
            }
        }
        $str .= '
<script>
    '.$this->js_code.'
</script>';
        return $str;
    }

    function generate_srcs(){
        var_dump($this->js_srcs);
        $str = '';
        if(count($this->js_srcs) > 0){
            foreach($this->js_srcs as $tag){
                $str .= $tag.'
';
            }
        }
        return $str;
    }

    function generate_code(){
        if($this->js_code != ''){
            return "<script>
            ".$this->js_code."</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php

$this->js->add_src(array('' => 'js/fileone.js', '' => 'js/filetwo.js', '' => 'js/filethree.js'));
$this->js->add_code('$("#element").myPlugin({});');
$this->js->add_src(array('js/global.js');

echo $this->js->generate_src();
echo $this->js->generate_code();
```

The script tag function:

```
    function script_tag($src = '', $type = '')
    {$str = '';
        $CI =& get_instance();
        if(is_array($src)){         
            foreach($src as $url){
                $str .= '<script ';
                if($type != ''){
                    $str .= 'type="'.$type.'" ';
                }               
                if(preg_match("^://^", $url)){ // If the url is absolute
                    $str .= 'src="'.$url.'"';
                } else { //If the url is relative
                    $str .= 'src="'.base_url($url).'"';
                }
                $str .= '></script>
';
            }
        } else {
            $str = '<script ';
            if($type != ''){
                $str .= 'type="'.$type.'" ';
            }
            $str .= 'src="'.$src.'"></script>
';
        }     
        return $str;                                
    }
```

Comment: Do you know what the array keys are? I've never tried to use '' as a key especially not for multiple keys. Perhaps the array is only one element and it's overwriting the same key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$this->js->add_src(array('' => 'js/fileone.js', '' => 'js/filetwo.js', '' => 'js/filethree.js'));
```

An associative array can only have one array with a particular key. You're trying to use the same key for all elements, so they overwrite each other. You need to give them different keys:

```
$this->js->add_src(array('type1' => 'js/fileone.js', 'type2' => 'js/filetwo.js', 'type3' => 'js/filethree.js'));
```

If you don't care about the keys, you can just use an ordinary indexed array:

```
$this->js->add_src(array('js/fileone.js', 'js/filetwo.js', 'js/filethree.js'));
```

PHP will automatically assign keys `0`, `1`, and so on.

Comment: How can I modify the add_src method so that it will only assign a "type" if the array is not auto-indexed?

Comment: Instead of checking whether the type is an empty string, check whether it's a number with `is_numeric()`.

Comment: A better approach: Instead of getting the type from the keys, use a 2-dimensional array. An array of `array('type'=>$type, 'url'=>$url)` sub-arrays.